# Loading Twitter feed in webview makes the back button enabled for the first time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, twitter, uiwebview

I have loaded a twitter url (http://mobile.twitter.com) in a webview. I have webview navigation button (back and next),which is to be disabled in the beginning. The back button gets enabled when I load a twitter feed. I did not navigate in the webview at all. When I click the back button and check it goes to a plain white screen.

To check this, I opened the Twitter URL in the Safari of the iPhone app. Even in Safari the back button gets enabled. Is this a bug? Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The request is probably being redirected, you can check it by placing a breakpoint in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method of your `UIWebViewDelegate`.